# Does SelectedItem.Text work in an if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a series of dropdown lists that on change are to call a function that converts overall value from binary to decimal and hex. I then have an if statement that checks that all lists have been changed. My If statement does not seem to be working correctly, and also if I choose 0 in a list the item switches back to --Select--.

Here is the dropdown list code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="r1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="convert" AutoPostBack="true" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the if statement

```
if (r1.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    r2.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" &&      
    r3.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    r4.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    r5.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    r6.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    r7.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    r8.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g1.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g2.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g3.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g4.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g5.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g6.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g7.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    g8.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b1.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b2.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b3.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b4.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b5.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b6.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b7.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--" && 
    b8.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select--")
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "test";
}
else
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "world";
}
```

Comment: Should work.  Make sure you check for nulls first, since r1.SelectedItem can be null and then accessing it's .Text property will throw a null reference exception.

Comment: It should work, if you do this at a good point of the pagecycle...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Convert.toString(r1.SelectedItem.Text) != "--Select--")
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "test";
}
else
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "world";
}
```

You can do like this and with the remainings

Comment: That still will throw exception if item is not selected

Comment: this function may only fire when the selected index is changed.

Answer (score 0):

As you have added `"--Select--"` at the top of the `dropdownlist`, then you can use the `DropDownList.SelectedIndex` property instead of `DropDownList.SelectedItem`. As MSDN says,

> `DropDownList.SelectedIndex` is the index of the selected item in the DropDownList control. The default value is 0, which selects the first item in the list.

The `if` part looks a bit messy. First clean it up by refactoring it using `Extract Method` like below:

```
private bool AreAllProperValuesSelected()
{
    return
        (r1.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r2.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r3.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r4.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r5.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r6.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r7.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (r8.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g1.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g2.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g3.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g4.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g5.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g6.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g7.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (g8.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b1.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b2.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b3.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b4.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b5.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b6.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b7.SelectedIndex != 0) &&
        (b8.SelectedIndex != 0);
}
```

You can use more shorter version of the above method like below:

```
private bool AreAllProperValuesSelected()
{
    var list = new List<DropDownList>
                   {
                       r1,
                       r2,
                       r3,
                       r4,
                       r5,
                       r6,
                       r7,
                       r8,
                       g1,
                       g2,
                       g3,
                       g4,
                       g5,
                       g6,
                       g7,
                       g8,
                       b1,
                       b2,
                       b3,
                       b4,
                       b5,
                       b6,
                       b7,
                       b8
                   };

    return list.TrueForAll(item => item.SelectedIndex != 0);
}
```

Then call it in the `if` part like below:

```
if (AreAllProperValuesSelected())
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "test";
}
else
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "world";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (r1.Text != "--Select--" && 
r2.Text != "--Select--" &&      
r3.Text != "--Select--" && 
r4.Text != "--Select--" && 
r5.Text != "--Select--" && 
r6.Text != "--Select--" && 
r7.Text != "--Select--" && 
r8.Text != "--Select--" && 
g1.Text != "--Select--" && 
g2.Text != "--Select--" && 
g3.Text != "--Select--" && 
g4.Text != "--Select--" && 
g5.Text != "--Select--" && 
g6.Text != "--Select--" && 
g7.Text != "--Select--" && 
g8.Text != "--Select--" && 
b1.Text != "--Select--" && 
b2.Text != "--Select--" && 
b3.Text != "--Select--" && 
b4.Text != "--Select--" && 
b5.Text != "--Select--" && 
b6.Text != "--Select--" && 
b7.Text != "--Select--" && 
b8.Text != "--Select--")
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "test";
}
else
{
    cBox.Attributes["InnerHtml"] = "world";
}
```